# Is there is any equivalent for the Android service in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I know that this question has been posted previously, but this is my case:

I'am using iBeacons to trigger a local push notification when the user enters a region (when the App is not in the memory), The local notification triggers successfully displaying the info that I want.

What I want is that I want to call a web service and display the result in the notification while the App is not in the memory, that also has been done successfully.

The problem is that I want the notification to be triggered once, that if the user entered and exited the region and he entered again he don't receive anther notification, I created a flag to keep track of that and it works fine in the run time (while the App is running) but I don't know how that work while the App is not running(is not in the memory), I tried it, and sometimes the notification triggers and sometimes not.

Comment: There are no services, but you shouldn't need one. You can simply persist the beacon region state using core data or NSUserDefaults

Comment: Yes that can be done, but I want to know how that state is being managed while the App is not in the foreground.
Why the notification sometimes triggers and sometimes not ?!

Comment: Beacon detention can be slower in the background. When your app is in the background it can be terminated and relaunched when the beacon is detected. For this reason you need to persist your data, you cannot rely on in-memory data

Answer (score 0):

CoreLocation manages state when an app is not running.  For each CLBeaconRegion registered by an app, the framework internally keeps track of whether it is "in" the region (beacons have been detected within the last 30 seconds of scanning) or not.

When this state changes, iOS will launch the app that registered the region into the background and Monitoring callbacks will fire.

Further app-specific state preservation is possible in custom coding.  An app can store a flag about whether it sent a notification in NSUserDefaults as @Paulw suggests.

Testing and debugging app launching via beacon detection can be tricky.  I suggest adding NSLog statements in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and in the CoreLocation callback methods.  You can look for these log statements in XCode Organizer -> Devices as iOS launces your app.